# How to run an Update Query instead of Insert for Count(1)

Tags: mysql, sql

The below sql query i require to run an update instead of an insert due to duplicates.

```
Insert into test_reports (Table_Name, Total_Count) SELECT "West Midlands", COUNT(1) FROM table1 where location = 'West Midlands'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A good way to deal with this problem is to differentiate between when there's no previous record and when there is a previous record. For that, you can use the [ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/insert-on-duplicate.html) phrase of an INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO **INSERT-PHRASE** ON DUPLICATE KEY **UPDATE-PHRASE**
```

Comment: This seems to be what i am looking for but how would i implement it in the query above? I can do basic Inserts and on Duplicate update instead but for some reason when using count(1) it gives a syntax error. Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `REPLACE INTO` instead.

More here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Note though that it deletes before it inserts, so any fields not in the query will be set to their defaults. If you do not want that behaviour, use `UPDATE`.

Comment: The OP appears to know that they need an update but can't work out the syntax.  Just saying `Use REPLACE INTO or UPDATE` doesn't help them...

Comment: It does, because just changing `INSERT` into `REPLACE` already works. If he is too lazy to read the documentation, he has no place here.

Comment: Replace Into is not what i am looking for as i would like to just update the Total_Count field by adding up the new amount. I have spent two days looking for this hence me seeing if someone could help here.